# MIgrating 4 tables to one new table in a new databse

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am migrating 4 tables to a new table. I am using **visual basic** 2008 `ExecuteNonQuery()`

My SQL skills are very rusty and maybe out of date (1998).

Here is my dilemma; I was pulling data from one table originally to make up a screen. Then the client decided to add a “Why” field, then an “Information” field etc…

Because the structure had to be backwards compatible new tables were added. Now I am combining them into one.

My problem is that not all the screens use all the tables; Screen may have a “Photo” and “Information” Field but not a “How” or “Why”

So I want to use the Primary key from one of the tables and add `INSERT` the rest.

Example: 
The first row may get the primary field from “Table1” and merge the rest into the same row.

The second row may not use “Table1” and I have no “Primary Key”???

I was considering getting the “Primary Key” and do a compare (this has a one to many) from the table that has the text, but that just adds another table?

I was also considering adding one table and the updating it with the rest in 4 steps?

Any advice would be appreciated. A SQL example would make my day…

Old Tables: Each has a primary key and one data field

```
Table1
PK  Data

Table2
PK  Data

Table3
PK  Data

Table4
PK  Data
```

New Table:  Has Primary key and 16 new columns
I am using `ExecuteNonQuery()`, so my pseudo code looks something like this;

```
SQLStr = "
Insert Into NewTable(PK, COL5, COL5, COL7, COL8, COL13, COL14, COL15, COL16) 
Select TABLE4.PK, TABLE4.DATA, TABLE2.PK, TABLES3.PK, TABLE1.PK, 'Photo','Information',
'Why', 'How' 
From Table1, Table2, table3, Table4 IN 'C:\Temp\oldDatabase.mdb'"
```

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea.  Could you provide more information on table 1-4's structure?

Comment: Tables 1-4 have a Primary Key (numeric) and One text field (50 Chrs)

Comment: Never mind, I used a series of left join to link it to my main text table. 

I had to add another table, so I imported from five and it works.

But if you have a simpler way, I would love to hear about it?